# Select a value from a specific column and compare it with other value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get only one value (varchar2 data type) from a specific record column of a table and store it as a variable to compare. Depending on the value and condition, I am going to call one of two cursors.

This all will be inside a function. So what's the easiest and shortest way to archive that? And, by the way, can this comparison be done directly without storing the value into a variable?
(I am kinda new in oracle world!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to get only one value (varchar2 data type) from a specific record column of a table"

You need to select this value into a variable, even if you are going to use it in the next statement.

> "depending of the value and condition, I am gonna call one of two cursors. "

Something like this:

```
create or replace function get_customers 
     return sys_refcursor
is
    rv  sys_refcursor;
    report_type your_table.some_col%type;
begin
    select some_col into report_type
    from your_table
    where other_col = 'WHATEVER';

    if report_type = 'CORPORATE' then
        open rv for 
            select * from customers 
            where type = 'CORP';
    else
        open rv for 
            select * from customers;
    end if;

    return rv;
end;
```

Comment: what for is this line `where type = 'CORP';` ?

Comment: Something to distinguish the two cursors. You didn't provide any details of what different queries you have so I made them up. Obviously you need to translate my toy code to your actual situation.

Comment: the queries of the cursors are the same in both cases, the only difference is that one has a join in it and the other not

Comment: Ok, now I understand that part. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I have an other question related to your answer. Example I want from the beginning, before I declare the cursor to make that check for that column record, and according to it set the query for the cursor. So just before the begin I check what the `report_type` value is. Can this be done?

Comment: No. Declarations are defined at compile time, and what you are describing is a runtime action. If you want to go down that route you will have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: So the select statement for the `report_type` must be inside the `Begin End`, except I use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SELECT INTO`:

```
DECLARE
    variable_name VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN

    SELECT col_name
    INTO variable_name
    FROM your_tab
    WHERE specific_column = value;

-- rest

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN ...
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN ...

END;
```

Of course you have to declare your cursor and wrap it with function (here I've used annonymous block).

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is being stored in a table, the comparison can be done directly by joining the table with the data to the cursor and adding to the where clause the specifics.

```
declare
  cursor cur_1 as
    select value1
    from table1 a
    join table2 b on a.fk = b.pk
    where b.value = 'desired_value';

  cursor cur_2 as
    select value2
    from table3 c
    join table4 d on c.fk = d.pk
    where d.value = 'desired_value2';

 begin
  for rec in cur_1 loop
    null;
  end loop;

  for rec2 in cur_2 loop
    null;
  end loop;
 end;
```

You could also use dynamic SQL and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to build a statement on the fly. Without more specific information about what you're trying to do it's hard to point you in a specific direction.

Comment: This is interesting, a different approach. But in your code you get both cursors called. But in my case I need only one of them, depending on the value of that column I am selecting.

Comment: Then you could wrap the cursor calls in a case statement

    case dependent_value
        when 'value1' then call cur_1
        when 'value2' then call cur_2...
    end case